# Java create tokens from txt file for hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been trying to `tokenize` a `dataset` of random tweets to do a `scan` for the most frequent words to get more into `mapreduce`. The data file is a .txt in the format:

```
tweetId "tab" tweetText
```

For example this could be a line:

```
1234     This is a tweet text
```

However since the data consists from tweets there are a lot of weird symbols and chars which are not actually text. I dont care if they appear in the list of counted words but they seem to mess up my tokenizer.

As an example there are a lot of `tab`s, and "`\u2026`"s in the strings. I tried to cover most of the breaking stuffs with the `replaceAll` statements but that did not work.

The error I'm getting is a `NoSuchElementException` from `util.StringTokenizer.nextToken`.

My map class is the following:

```
@Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        line = line.replaceAll(",", "");
        line = line.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        line = line.replaceAll("-", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("@", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("\"", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("\"+'u'", " ");
        line = line.replaceAll("\"+'.....'", "");

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        int tweetId = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase());
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help if anyone has a better idea how to `tokenize` the dataset. I was thinking of inserting a special character but could not get it to work that way.

Comment: I would recommend using `split` instead of `StringTokenizer` function

Comment: That's what i did afterwards, totally forgotten this question due to university being stressfull. thanks for the answer though, sorry for the late aknowledgement!